# Reading multiple inputs from Dart Console

Tags: dart, dart-io

I want to read different data from the console in a Dart server application, like:

forename  : user inputs and enters
 lastname  : user inputs and enters
 age       : user inputs and enters

The following code works, but for 1 input item only:

```dart
var stream = new StringInputStream(stdin);
stream.onData = () {
    voornaam = stream.readLine();
};
```

But I can't get it to work for multiple items.
Is there an easy way to do this in Dart ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a `StringInputStream` rather than just a standard `InputStream`, and because you're looking to read text. Unless there's a particular reason, I would recommend using the `onLine` handler over the `onData`. On data will basically try to 'stream' the information in that it's called immediately not on a new line itself. Try something like the following (note, not complete code, missing proper error handling etc.)

```dart
#import('dart:io');

main() {
  var stream = new StringInputStream(stdin);
  stream.onLine = () {
    var str = stream.readLine().trim();
    print(str.toUpperCase());
    if(str == 'EXIT') exit(0);
  };
}
```

One other note to point out, if you ever are data-streaming and using the `onData` handler, it is recommended that you then use the `read` method, as opposed to the `readLine` method to retrieve your content, again due to the nature of onData not waiting for a full line of text to be received before being called.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print('-----welcome-----');
  print('what is your firstname');
  var fname = stdin.readLineSync();
  print('what is your lastname');
  var lname = stdin.readLineSync();
  print('what is your age');
  int age = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  int left = 100 - age;
  print('your name is $fname $lname  and you are  $age years');
}
```